# Upgrading Django from 1.8.6 to 1.9--django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet; importing models issue

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to upgrade from Django 1.8.6 to 1.9 but I've been running into trouble with trying to get the project to build and run properly. I've changed numerous things necessary for the upgrade, like making an `apps.py` file in `my_app` and defining Configs and including their dotted paths in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` (and changing `INSTALLED_APPS` to a list), but the same error I get every time is:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

For some background info, the project uses Docker Compose. The Dockerfile used for the `web` container which runs the Django server itself utilizes `paver` to start up so that when `docker-compose up` is run, the following commands are executed:

```
./manage.py makemigrations --noinput
./manage.py migrate --noinput
./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

To my knowledge, none of the dependencies are incompatible with Django 1.9 so I'm not sure if that's the issue here. The only dependency that I initially thought could have been incompatible was `django_hstore`, but it was updated for compatibility shortly after 1.9 was officially released. So unless the creator of `django_hstore` is mistaken or lying (which I doubt), I can't really think of any incompatible dependencies. The database backend used is `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`. There is also a `worker` container that uses the same Dockerfile as `web` and is used to run Celery. The full error traceback from the Django `worker` container is below:

```
worker_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
worker_1 |     sys.exit(main())
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
worker_1 |     main()
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
worker_1 |     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 770, in execute_from_commandline
worker_1 |     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
worker_1 |     argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
worker_1 |     self.app = self.find_app(app)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
worker_1 |     return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 238, in find_app
worker_1 |     sym = imp(app)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
worker_1 |     return imp(module, package=package)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
worker_1 |     __import__(name)
worker_1 |   File "/code/my_app/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
worker_1 |     from taskman.celery import app, DBTask
worker_1 |   File "/code/taskman/celery.py", line 6, in <module>
worker_1 |     from utils.db.clearblackbox import rm_invalid_blackbox
worker_1 |   File "/code/utils/db/clearblackbox.py", line 9, in <module>
worker_1 |     django.setup()
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
worker_1 |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
worker_1 |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 142, in create
worker_1 |     app_module = import_module(app_name)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
worker_1 |     __import__(name)
worker_1 |   File "/code/utils/db/blackboxquery.py", line 2, in <module>
worker_1 |     from my_app.models import BlackBox, DataPoint, Value, SourceInfo, FormatString, Argument
worker_1 |   File "/code/my_app/models.py", line 11, in <module>
worker_1 |     class Value(models.Model):
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
worker_1 |     app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
worker_1 |     self.check_apps_ready()
worker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
worker_1 |     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
worker_1 | django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I've seen a number of similar questions that had the same AppRegistryNotReady exception when upgrading to 1.9 but in my case I can specifically tell it's because one of my apps whose AppConfig is in `apps.py` imports models when it is recommended to not do so. The Django 1.9 documentation on application setup says:

> At this stage, your code shouldn’t import any models!
>
> In other words, your applications’ root packages and the modules that define your application configuration classes shouldn’t import any models, even indirectly.
>
> Strictly speaking, Django allows importing models once their application configuration is loaded. However, in order to avoid needless constraints on the order of INSTALLED_APPS, it’s strongly recommended not import any models at this stage.

Unfortunately, the documentation seems to offer no alternative for importing models during the setup stage, which is a shame since I can't actually avoid importing models. Specifically, in my `celery.py`, I have a `Task` subclass named `DBTask` whose `on_error` callback uses a module function to remove an invalid database insertion. That module, `clearblackbox.py`, imports models since it needs to call `delete()` on the invalid model that was inserted into the database. The `DBTask` class is used as the base class for the main database insertion task named `insertBlackboxIntoDatabaseTask`. Since I can't get around importing models at the `setup()` stage, what else can I do to get past this error and be able to run my server again?

***EDIT:*** I was wondering if I had any unnecessary Configs so I got rid of all but two: `my_app.apps.TasksConfig`, whose `name` field points to my `tasks.py` containing the definition of my database insertion task, and `taskman.celery.CeleryConfig`, which overrides `ready` such that it auto-detects tasks from among `INSTALLED_APPS`. Though I put `taskman.celery.CeleryConfig` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, the error I get now is

```
ImportError: No module named CeleryConfig
```

This happens if I put `import django` and `django.setup()` in either `celery.py` or `clearblackbox.py` in an attempt to solve the `AppRegistryNotReady` exception that is happening due to importing models during setup.

Comment: I saw a similar bug to this as a regression in the Django 1.8.x series. It meant that one of the apps in INSTALLED_APPS wasn't available for import. Can you try importing each app from INSTALLED_APPS from the Python shell in your virtualenv? That might find the culprit.

Comment: @FlipperPA You might be misunderstanding here. I'm using Docker Compose so there's no virtualenv. I already know which app is not available for import--it's the one with my CeleryConfig because it's indirectly importing models. What I was asking was not which app might be the culprit but how to get around the import problem that I described in the question.

Comment: @AviahLaor In `views.py` I have upload functions that end up calling database insertion tasks that are run with celery. In my `docker-compose.yml` file I have a Celery container named `worker` that is run with the command `bash -c "celery worker --app=my_app.tasks --autoreload -l DEBUG"`.

Comment: It seems that Celery is called before django setup is complete. Try to move these functions from these views. App registry is available only after `import django;django.setup()` is ready

Comment: Not possible, I'm afraid. These upload functions need to be in `views.py` since they're called from APIViews which use Django REST Framework. It's not really an option to drastically refactor the code to take these upload functions out of `views.py`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct @DanK - I had too many tabs open and got my wires crossed between this and another question! My apologies.

Comment: Have you tried moving the problematic import into the function (Celery task) instead of having it at the module level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was getting rid of all Configs in `apps.py` except for the `TasksConfig`, then modifying the imports in `clearblackbox.py` and `celery.py`. In `clearblackbox.py`, I moved the model import into the function itself instead of leaving it at the top and in `celery.py`, I moved the import of the function from `clearblackbox.py` into the `on_failure` definition for `DBTask` rather than leave the import at the top. After doing this, putting the dotted paths to the `TasksConfig` and `CeleryConfig` ended up working.